# How to get difficulty from Fairbrix/Tenebrix?

Tags: tenebrix

How can I get the difficulty of Fairbrix or Tenebrix directly from the client? Without using an external site.

I use "getinfo" with Bitcoin but with Fairbrix/Tenebrix, "getinfo" doesn't return anything.
I'm running it with their somewhat unstable "portable launcher".

Thanks!

Comment: The `getinfo` RPC should work precisely the same on Fairbrix or Tenebrix as it does with the Bitcoin client. Are you running the GUI version or non-GUI version of the client? Are you sure you're enabling the client's RPC server?

Comment: I'm running the GUI version. I'm running it through their "portable launcher" because I get debug assertion errors when I try running the exe directly :\ Good to know it's been coded to a high standard huh. And I have server=1 and daemon=1 in my config.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most straightforward way would be going to [www.allchains.info](http://www.allchains.info)

No need to bother with command line and stuff.

Comment: At the time of writing the question, fairbrix wasn't included on allchains.info.